# How to parse and echo multiple file paths using batch

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch file that will echo or print the path of a file. Apparently, I am unable to print the path when I send multiple files as parameters to the said batch file.

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set string=%1
set string=!string:\=%%5C!

@echo %string% > D:\Playground\test.txt
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If there's anything unclear please let me know. Thanks.

Note: I send files to the batch file using the procedure below:

- Right Click File
- Send to
- Choose the menu item that I created in sendTo that will pass the file to batch file

I don't know if this info helps but I didn't want to leave it out of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%*` will catch each input string passed separated by whitespace, `enabledelayedexpansion` should be used as you do `set` inside of a code block (). We also enclose the variables, including variable name with double quotes:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (%*) do (
 set "string=%%~a"
 set "string=!string:\=%%5C!"
 echo !string! >> D:\Playground\test.txt
)
```

As you can see, you need to use the `for` loop to iterate each of the input strings i.e `%1` `%2` and `%3` etc.

As a *Side note* You can also drag and drop files onto the batch file to get results.

**EDIT**

Added the quote removal as requested `set "string=!string:"=!"` but note that using the strings as paths without quoting them will cause an issue in future if the paths contains whitespace.

To pipe to file without newline:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (%*) do (
 set "string=%%~a"
 set "string=!string:\=%%5C!"
 echo|set /p="!string! " >> D:\Playground\test.txt
)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. But is it possible to print them with out the quotes and the new llines?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. It worked as expected. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To remove outer double quotes I'd simply use `set "string=%%~a"`